# Implicit declaration of function in doubly linked list using C

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, function-declaration, implicit-declaration

This isn't the final implementation of the program, but the program itself was a bit long so I decided to create it in small chunks instead. I'm running into an error that says

> implicit declaration of function list_first.

There are other errors to tackle, but I would like to get some help with this first and then work on the rest myself, although you are welcome to give out extra help if you feel like it. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// The type for a node in the list.
struct node
{
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
    char *value;
};

// The type for a list.
typedef struct list
{
    struct node head;
} List;

// The type for a list position.
typedef struct list_pos
{
    struct node *node;
} ListPos;

List *list_create(void)
{
  List *lst = (List*)malloc(sizeof(List));
  if(lst == NULL)
  {
    printf("No more memory!\n");
  }

  return lst;
}

static struct node *make_node(const char *value)
{
  struct node *result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  result->value = strdup(value);
  result -> next = NULL;
  result -> prev = NULL;
  return result;
}
static void add_values(List *lst)
{
    ListPos pos = list_first(lst);
    pos = list_insert(pos, "Apple");
    pos = list_next(pos);
    pos = list_insert(pos, "Banana");
    pos = list_next(pos);
    pos = list_insert(pos, "Citrus");
}

ListPos list_end(List *lst)
{
    ListPos pos = {
        .node = &lst->head
    };
    return pos;
}

ListPos list_first(List *lst)
{
    ListPos pos = {
        .node = lst->head.next
    };
    return pos;
}
ListPos list_next(ListPos pos)
{
  struct node* node;

  //pos = node -> next;
  struct node *before = pos.node->prev;
  struct node *after = pos.node;

   node->next = after;
   after->prev = node;

  pos.node = node;
    return pos;
}
ListPos list_insert(ListPos pos, const char *value)
{
    // Create a new node.
    struct node *node = make_node(value);

    // Find nodes before and after (may be the same node: the head of the list).
    struct node *before = pos.node->prev;
    struct node *after = pos.node;

    // Link to node after.
    node->next = after;
    after->prev = node;

    // Link to node before.
    node->prev = before;
    before->next = node;

    // Return the position of the new element.
    pos.node = node;
    return pos;
}


int main(void)
{

    // Create an empty list.

      List *lst = list_create();
      add_values(lst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A function needs to be declared *before* it is being used.

Comment: You need to move `list_first` above `add_values` where it's called, or add a function prototype for it at the top of the file or in a header file.

Comment: Or move `add_values` down so it is just above `main`.

Comment: if malloc fails in `list_create`, you are printing an error message but not actually handling the error.  Rather than letting the program encounter a run time error later, you should probably `exit`.  Also, print the error message to stderr.

Comment: Since `add_values()` calls a number of previously undeclared, undefined functions, it is best placed after the functions it is called are all defined.  Or provide forward declarations for the functions.  If you were creating a doubly-linked list module, you'd have the source code in one file (e.g. `dll.c`) and the function declarations in a header (e.g. `dll.h`), and the program in a third file (e.g. `test-dll.c`). Both the `dll.c` and `dll-test.c` files would `#include "dll.h"` to see the declarations. The `add_values()` function would be in the `test-dll.c` file, not the `dll.c` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `add_values`

```
static void add_values(List *lst)
{
    ListPos pos = list_first(lst);
    //..
```

there is called the function `list_first` that was not yet declared.

You need to place a declaration of the function `list_first` before its usage in the function `add_values`.

For example

```
ListPos list_first(List *lst);

static void add_values(List *lst)
{
    ListPos pos = list_first(lst);
    //..
```

Pay attention to that this declaration

```
typedef struct list
{
    struct node head;
} List;
```

does not make a great sense. You should use the following declaration of the list

```
typedef struct list
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node *tail;
} List;
```

The function `list_create` does not initialize the data member of the dynamically allocated object.

So other functions as for example `list_first` invoke undefined behavior accessing the uninitialized data member `head` as in this declaration

```
ListPos pos = {
    .node = lst->head.next
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be the prototype of the function or the function definition itself before the line in which the function is used. Add prototype definitions after typedef declarations for the function and other functions you specify.

Comment: You're correct, but can you show the revised code, or an outline of the revised code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> implicit declaration of function list_first.

This means the compiler has seen a function call called `list_first`, but you (or the include files you use in the compilation unit) have not provided the interface to that function (the type returned by it, or the list and types of the arguments passed to it)  In old C, this was permitted, assuming by default (which can be probably too dare) the function returns an `int` value and takes an undefined list of parameters, as defined by this prototype (which probably is not the correct one):

```
int list_first();
```

So you probably need to provide  a correct definition for that function in a header file (if the function was written by you) and `#include` it in your source file, or just `#include` the file in which a definition for the function is given.

Old versions of the standard allowed this, with the default behaviour shown above in the compiler, but recent versions of the standard forbid it (well, if you wrote the function, why don't include a header file that tells the compiler how to use it? or if you didn't, why let the compiler guess and don't provide a correct interface?)

Comment: "Recent" means "compilers conforming to C99 or later" — though it was only with GCC 5.0.0 that GCC defaulted to a version of the standard other than C90 (and, in doing so, set the default to C11, meaning C99 was never the default standard for GCC).

Comment: Recent means that if you compile with C99 the use of that will be banned with an error message, while in previous standards you get, as it is shown in the question, just a warning message.  I'm not a follower of the C standards, I meant Recent, everything after C89 (not after or equals)